Cannot register on wiki.ros.org
I'm interested in creating my own ros-package. And I'd like to share it with the ros community.
For signing up I followed by the wiki.ros.org/HelpOnLogin webpage. But as soon as I press the new account page I receive this message:

Do you have any ideas why I cannot register in ros wiki?

looks like new accounts cannot be registered

The ROS Wiki was replaced by the ROS Index.

So, is it main place for ROS packages distribution nowadays?

You do not and cannot register on the old wiki.ros.org.
@AntonLedrov Browse to https://index.ros.org/contribute/#adding-ros-packages and click the "Add a repository to the index" button to see exactly how to make your code available to the ROS community.   Yes, it "is the main place for ROS packages distribution nowadays"
And you should mark the JRTG answer as the answer to your question.
